# Column default value settings on folders created when creating Ms Teams channel

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, microsoft-teams

I am migrating sites from SharePoint On Premise to SharePoint Online/Ms Teams. We have not been using folders in our document libraries, instead we have relied on managed metadata. For one of the new sites, I created the site as an Ms Teams, and then I set up a number of channels, one for each sub-process (that we have metadata for). So I got the corresponding folders in my SharePoint library, one for each channel.

I would now like to have the files added to the folders tagged with the sub-process metadata for that folder automatically. But when I go to "Column default value setting" I can see none of the folders that exist in the library. I can just set default values for the document library.

How can I get the folders created by Ms Teams to display in "Column default value settings"?

Comment: Do you want a different metadata value applied to the document based on which folder it was added to?

Comment: Yes, if the document was added to the "Process 1" folder (from the channel of from SharePoint), I want the document to be tagged with "Process 1" in the Process column. It is Ms Teams that introduced this idea with folders in the document library, but we have applications from the SharePoint site where we need to have the metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a Power Automate flow that is triggered when an item is added to the Documents library. The flow could check which folder the file has been added to and then set the column value for the file.

Comment: Since the very handy "Column default value setting" is not available anymore, where it was possible to map to managed metadata before, I guess a PA flow is the only way to go, but I will need to have 15 different flows, one for each process... And I am not sure how get the managed metadata values to to the flow, but I am learning the tricks of REST calls now...

Comment: Default values are still available, they're set at document library level rather than folder level (this has always been the case however).